# Как сделать, чтобы все файлы в моем приложении автоматически подключались при обращении к серверу? Например, при отправки формы?

Tags: php

Я хочу, чтобы все файлы в моем приложении автоматически подключались при обращении к серверу. Как это сделать?
Чтобы в save_comment.php, в read_comment.php и тд не требовалось писать require_once "Helper.php"; require_once "db.php"; 
Написать один файл, в котором все это будет подключаться? А как отправлять форму? Точнее, куда? Придется на этот файл - чтобы все подключилось. Но как тогда обработать форму на сервере, если все формы отправляются на один и тот же файл - на файл сборки?

Comment: Почитайте http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 0):

в общем все довольно просто в своем index.php регистрируете `autoload`

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once('/class/path/' . $class . '.php');
});
```

Либо конвертируете `namespace` и получаете путь до файла к примеру класс

класс: \Test\Test\Test
его фаил: /Test/Test/Test.php

и так далее, если у вас не ооп можно использовать вариант со сканированием директории

```
foreach(glob('/inc/(.*).php') as $_file) {
   require_once($_file);
}
```

и включить это в каждый фаил. 
При этом если роуты обрабатываются в разных файлах а не в index.php то придется сделать файл `autoload.php` там зарегистрировать автолоад и инклудить к каждому исполняемому файлу.

Далее можно упомянуть что можно использовать сгенерированый composer'ом `autoload` 
В корне проекта создоем файл composer.json с содержимым

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "path/to/directory",
    ]
  }
}
```

и выполняем команду

> composer dump-autoload

и далее в файлах добавляем строку

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

p.s. `glob` писал по памяти и мог ошибиться. Редко использую.